# How to configure TFS burn down chart to be for story points

Tags: tfs

Out of the box TFS only has an hour burn-down chart.
We need a burn-down based on story-points.
It should use the "effort" field on PBI/Story to burn down once a story is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own report based on TFS data (warehouse or cube). You can find more on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649552.aspx

Comment: I need more precisely configure TFS burn  down chart to be for story points, in fact i have done much customization but am not sure on how to implement this change.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the web access.

Herbert of you have the reporting component configured you get an out of the box reporting services burn down report. If you open that you can change the burn from hours, to tasks, or story points.

However reporting services is not team aware.

Comment: • The Sprint Burndown (Scrum) report. This is the report we want to use as basis and extend it
• The Burndown And Burn Rate (Agile) report. This report has the option to switch between Number of hours and Number of tasks, this mechanism should be usable for our purpose as well.
• The Release Burndown report (Scrum). This report is the larger brother of the Sprint burndown by story pont. It is the burndown of storypoitns across iterations.
Extend this mechanism to show the Number of Story Points based on the “Effort” field and the State of the stories.